# Button on the GMSMapView (Google Map) using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

As I am new to Swift programming and also iOS development, I am facing problem of placing button on top of Google Map.

I have been using Google Map SDK for iOS using Cocopods, and example from Google Map API guide.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true;
    self.view = mapView

    var marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView

}
```

I want to place button above the map.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create a `UIButton` and add it to your view after adding the map, as the last thing in your `viewDidLoad` should be fine.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: whereYouWant)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: Glad to know. Feel free to mark the answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Your comment does not have enough information to be helpful

Comment: felipe can you see my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440728/add-some-button-to-gmsmapview-google-map-and-change-the-image-button?noredirect=1#comment91824428_52440728)

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you have a google map view called "googleMapView"
and a UIButton called "yourButton"

Make sure that you insert your GooglemapView underneath the button by doing this:

```
self.view.insertSubview(googleMapView, atIndex: 0)
self.view.insertSubview(yourButton, atIndex: 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing something like this inside your ViewController class, maybe in the viewDidLoad() method:

Assuming that the `self.view` is an instance of GmsMapView, like this,
`self.view = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: someCamera)`.

```
let btn: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.roundedRect)
btn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 30)
btn.setTitle("MyButton", for: UIControlState.normal)
self.view.addSubview(btn)
```

For `XCode 11`

```
let btn: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.roundedRect)
btn.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 30)
btn.setTitle("MyButton", for: UIControl.State.normal)
self.view.addSubview(btn)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried several options but got no result. Finally found that after implementing **GoogleMap** on a **view** implement a **button** or anything else after that, like this :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Google Maps

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    view = mapView

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView

    // Add a button
    let revealButton = UIButton()
    let btnImage = UIImage(named: "reveal-icon")
    revealButton.setImage(btnImage, for: .normal)
    revealButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 38, width: 48, height: 41)
    self.view.addSubview(revealButton)

    // RevealViewController for button.
    let revealViewController = self.revealViewController()
    revealButton.addTarget(revealViewController,
                         action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to put the Map and Items on it.
Create your button and every thing you want on the **UIViewController**
if you have **any UIView covering the default UIView** on the ViewController, make them background color as **Clear Color** then add following code in **viewDidLoad()**

```
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 17.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.view.insertSubview(mapView, at: 0)

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.title = "Main Title"
    marker.snippet = "Deescription"
    marker.map = mapView
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
self.okBtnOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(placeMarkerPointOnDrag), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc  func placeMarkerPointOnDrag(){
    self.placeMarkerOnMapOnButtonTap(coordinate: self.draggingCoordinate)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didEndDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
    print("End dragging")
    let coordinate = mapView.myLocation!.coordinate
    print(coordinate)
    self.draggingCoordinate = marker.position
    // self.placeMarkerOnMapOnButtonTap(coordinate: marker.position)
}

func placeMarkerOnMapOnButtonTap(coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) {
        response, error in
        //
        if error != nil {
            print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else {
            if let places = response?.results() {
                if let place = places.first {
                    if let lines = place.lines {
                        print("GEOCODE: Formatted Address: \(lines)")
                        let temp = CoordinatesValue(lineString: lines.first ?? "", title: "", lat: coordinate.latitude, long: coordinate.longitude, isSelect: false, isCompleted: false)
                        self.locArray.append(temp)
                    }
                    if let newPlace = place.postalCode{
                        print(newPlace)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print("GEOCODE: nil first in places")
                }
            }
            else {
                print("GEOCODE: nil in places")
            }
        }
    }

    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
    let  marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.title = ""
    marker.map = self.googleMapView
    self.selectedCoordinate = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
    //    let distanceInMeters : CLLocationDistance = self.currentCoordinate.distance(from: selectedCoordinate)
    //   print(distanceInMeters)
    print("The CURRENT LAT \(lat) & LONG \(long)")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions here is good but this answer would be much more useful if it was properly formatted and if there was an explanation of what the code does and how it solves the question.