# add some button to GMSMapView (Google Map) and change the image button

Tags: ios, button, swift3, gmsmapview

I try but can't show the button

**Code:**

```
btnLokasiSaya = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 341, y: 28, width: 100, height: 30))
self.viewMap.addSubview(btnLokasiSaya)
```

**StoryBoard:**

[image]

**Output:** my button is not found in simulation

[image]

Comment: Try to add button outside the map

Comment: my question add some button inside not outside

Comment: If u add button as map subview it wont reflect in UI

Comment: how can reflect ?

Comment: Reflect In the sense button wont display in your UI

Comment: can you help me to build it can ?

Comment: ok thanks you very much

Comment: your answer it's right. my misstake in my storyboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Main.Storyboard` add button outside the `mapview` as shown below:

[image]

Comment: @Firuma let me know for further queries.

Comment: thanks you very much , it's so simple but i don't see